# MFMessageComposeViewController without text field

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a native view controller available (in iOS 5) similar to `MFMessageComposeViewController` but without the message field? Basically I just need to pick contacts from the address book just like the iCal **Invitees** picker *but with the token field and search table*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented my own picker with tokenizing text field and contacts picker.
Have a look and feel free to use & extend.

https://github.com/eaigner/COPeoplePickerViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pick some people from the address book, then that's what he [`ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController) is for.

Comment: I know about that, but that controller does not provide a token field like I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at ABPeoplePickerNavigationController? This is for browsing the address book.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html